# How to find and replace src and href from a string?

Tags: vb.net, regex, string

```
Dim r As String

If r.Contains("src") Then
     r.Replace("src=\""", "")
    'r.Replace("src='{0}'", "src='http://google.co.in'")
End If
Response.Write(r.ToString())
Response.End()
```

Comment: I think you are trying to do something with html, but, could you please clarify your question.

Comment: Agreed.  Maybe you accidently hit submit...  More info please.

Comment: @null, that's not helpful at all...Please try to be more constructive.  I don't disagree with the downvote, but "What the hell?" doesn't improve the situation at all.

Comment: @Justin Duly noted. I am too tired I guess.

Comment: I tagged it VB.net as a guess.

Answer (score 1):

Unsure what you mean but it looks like you want to use RegEx replacement. However, Replace methods on String do not support it with your specific syntax.